# What does the shell script in git-stash mean and how does it work?

Tags: git, bash, shell, sh, git-stash

I saw code snippets like this in `git-stash`

```
            rm -f "$TMP-index" &&
            GIT_INDEX_FILE="$TMP-index" git read-tree HEAD &&


            # find out what the user wants
            GIT_INDEX_FILE="$TMP-index" \
                    git add--interactive --patch=stash -- &&

            # state of the working tree
            w_tree=$(GIT_INDEX_FILE="$TMP-index" git write-tree) ||
            die "$(gettext "Cannot save the current worktree state")"

            git diff-tree -p HEAD $w_tree -- >"$TMP-patch" &&
            test -s "$TMP-patch" ||
            die "$(gettext "No changes selected")"

            rm -f "$TMP-index" ||
            die "$(gettext "Cannot remove temporary index (can't happen)")"
```

What I don't understand is the expression like this:

```
GIT_INDEX_FILE="$TMP-index" git read-tree HEAD
```

Does that mean assign the value of `TMP-index` to `GIT_INDEX_FILE`, and then execute command `git read-tree HEAD`?

I'm not sure about that. So I tried to write a similar command like this.

```
A="1" ls
echo $A
```

The value of `A` is still `null`.

I also tried this:

```
echo $a
=> 1
k=$(a=100 echo $a)
=> 
echo $k
=> 1
```

It looks that the value of `a` is not changed at all. So the `a=100` seems useless..

Does anyone have ideas about syntax like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean assign the value of `TMP-index` to `GIT_INDEX_FILE`, and
>   then execute command `git read-tree HEAD`?

Not quite.  The syntax:

```sh
VAR1=val1 VAR2=val2 somecommand arg1 arg2
```

tells the shell to execute the command `somecommand` with arguments `arg1` and `arg2`, but `somecommand`'s environment will have `VAR1` set to `val1` and `VAR2` set to `val2`.  The shell itself won't be affected by those assignments, only the environment of `somecommand`.  The effect is equivalent to:

```sh
env VAR1=val1 VAR2=val2 somecommand arg1 arg2
```

The only difference is that the former method does not require finding and executing the `/usr/bin/env` utility (I'm assuming `env` is not a shell built-in utility), so it's a hair faster.

It is also equivalent to:

```sh
(export VAR1=val1 VAR2=val2; somecommand arg1 arg2)
```

Notice the parentheses -- this causes the shell to execute the commands in a separate subshell.  Any changes to a subshell (such as variable assignments) do not persist when the subshell ends.

### Example

```sh
#!/bin/sh
FOO=value1
printf %s\\n "In the shell, FOO is ${FOO} (before running python)"
FOO=value2 python -c 'import os; print "In python, FOO is", os.environ["FOO"]'
printf %s\\n "In the shell, FOO is ${FOO} (after running python)"
```

The above script prints the following output:

```
In the shell FOO is value1 (before running python)
In python, FOO is value2
In the shell, FOO is value1 (after running python)
```

### What Git is doing

In the snippet of Git shell code you provided, `git stash` is temporarily changing `GIT_INDEX_FILE` for a few invocations of `git` so that `stash` can perform some index-mutating operations without messing up your index:

- First, `git stash` uses `git read-tree` to create the temporary index file and initialize its contents to whatever is in `HEAD`.
- Second, `git stash` uses `git add --interactive` to ask the user which parts to stash and saves the chosen changes in the temporary index file.
- Third, `git stash` uses `git write-tree` to save the contents of the temporary index as a tree object in your Git repository.
- Fourth, `git stash` compares the tree object to `HEAD` to make sure you actually selected something to stash.
- Finally, `git stash` deletes the temporary index file it created.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question "Does that mean..." is **yes**.

However, the variable expansion happens when the command is parsed, which would be too early to see the result of setting an environment variable and then importing it into a shell, and that's why you aren't getting the results you expect.

There are various ways to see the result of a one-line environment variable expression; you could observe...

```
$ B=100 env | grep B
B=100
```

...or...

```
$ z=abc sh -c 'echo $z'
abc
```

Answer (score 1):

In BASH, there are some issues with defining a variable and running a new process afterward.

If you just define the variable, it is not 'inherited' by the new processes

Lets define a variable

```
$ VAR='value'
$ echo $VAR
value
```

And then go into a new process

```
$ bash
```

The var is undefined

```
$ echo $VAR

$
```

But once we get back

```
$ exit
```

the var is defined again

```
$ echo $VAR
value
$
```

the usual way around this is to use export

```
$ export VAR2='yep'
$ bash
$ echo $VAR2
yep
$
```

what you are seeing (seems to be) an alternate syntax for that, that assigns the variable in the child process, but not in the original process

```
$ var3='wow' bash  #this line opens a new bash, and assigns the variable for this new bash
$ echo $var3
wow
$ exit
$ echo $var3

$
```